# -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `(' for multiplication of numbers

Tags: bash

Just trying to run the following command:

```
python preprocess.py -train_src data/train.txt.src \
    -train_tgt data/train.txt.tgt \
    -valid_src data/val.txt.src \
    -valid_tgt data/val.txt.tgt \
    -save_data data/radiology_data \
    -src_seq_length 10000 \
    -tgt_seq_length 10000 \
    -src_seq_length_trunc 400 \
    -tgt_seq_length_trunc 100 \
    -dynamic_dict \
    -share_vocab \
    -max_shard_size(500 * 1024 * 1024)
```

But getting this error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing that argument as following:
`-max_shard_size $((500 * 1024 * 1024))`